# postgres row to column

Tags: postgresql, pivot

I have this pretty straightforward SQL query

```
SELECT count(date_mdy) AS unique_date_count,
  county,
  date_s
FROM (
  SELECT date_mdy,
    county,
    date_s 
  FROM air_quality2
  GROUP BY county, date_s ,date_mdy 
  ORDER BY county, date_s
) AS t1 
GROUP BY county, date_s 
ORDER BY date_s;
```

this returns

[image]

I want the county names to be the column headers. I know there is a crosstab function and I have seen the many posts on here where they use it but I cannot get it to work on this query.

Comment: @EvanCarroll it is not dynamic, always the same amount of counties. Also I didnt know you can use distinct inside an aggregate function, wow thats super useful and less code

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As I said, simplify it using `count(DISTINCT...)`

```
SELECT county,
  date_s,
  count(DISTINCT date_mdy) AS unique_date_count
FROM air_quality2
GROUP BY county,
  date_s
ORDER BY 1,2;
```

Now wrap it in [`crosstab`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/tablefunc.html)

```
SELECT *
FROM crosstab($$
    SELECT county,
      date_s::int,
      count(DISTINCT date_mdy) AS unique_date_count 
    FROM air_quality2
    GROUP BY county,
      date_s
    ORDER BY 1,2;
  $$,
  $$ SELECT DISTINCT county FROM air_quality2; $$
)
AS ct(
  year               int,
  "Bergen County"    int,
  "Essex County"     int,
  "Hunterdon County" int,
  "Middlesex County" int,
  "Monmouth County"  int,
  "Morris County"    int,
  "Union County"     int
);
```

**Update**

1. forgot to put the row_name `year` in the definition.
2. You may have to cast `date_s` to int
3. You may have to cast `count(DISTINCT...)` to int, (or bigint and change the types).
4. You will have to make sure you gave all the counties in your sample data. Or, paste the results of `SELECT DISTINCT county FROM air_quality2;`.